# Create and Install own OpenAI Gym Environment

Tags: python, openai-gym

I currently runs Spyder Python editor under Anaconda 3.
I have followed the instruction from the link below to create my test gym environment. 
https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/envs#how-to-create-new-environments-for-gym

However, when I try to install it using the codes below in the Anaconda Prompt as administrator:

```
pip install gym
pip install -e .
```

All I got was an error message of "Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
Even know I have setup.py in the root folder.

Here's the link to my own gym:
https://github.com/stewegg/DanL-gym

Can someone assist me with this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have also some problems with installing my own enviroments. But in my path of troubleshooting I crashed in same problems as you did. The line

```py
File 'setup.py' not found.
```

explains what the problem is very good. You have to change you path to the directory where your `setup.py` File is located and then run

```py
pip install -e .
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Prompt, you can install it by typing

`pip install gym --user` if you are getting errors. You can find more information at [here](https://pypi.org/project/gym/0.7.4/).

In Anaconda Prompt, I have installed it with the same as before by typing

`pip install gym`.

Try that, and if you are getting errors type here.